# Simplify $q=\frac{0.9\times0.1^2}{9\times10^9\times1\times10^{-6}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am solving a physics problem and I got that $q=\dfrac{0.9\times0.1^2}{9\times10^9\times1\times10^{-6}}.$ I simplified and we have $q=\dfrac{0.1^3}{10^3}.$ How is this equal to $1\times10^{-6}$?

Comment: $0.1=10^{-1}\implies q = (0.1)^3 \times 10^{-3} = 10^{-3}\times 10^{-3} = 10^{-6}$

Comment: 0.1 is equal to 10^-1, so 0.1^3=10^-3, and the 10^3 at the denominator is also 10^-3 so adding up the exponents you get 10^(-3-3)=10^-6

Comment: $0.1 = 10^{-1}$.  So $0.1^3 = 10^{-3}$ and so $\frac {0.1^3}{10^3} = \frac {10^{-3}}{10^3} = 10^{-3-3} = 10^{-6}$.  .... Alternativily  $\frac {0.1^3}{10^3} = \frac {0.001}{1000}=(0.001)\times(0.0001) = 0.000001 = 10^{-6}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scientific notation is about putting things into powers of $10$ (both positive and negative) and adding and subtracting to go a single $10$ to a single power.

$0.1 = 10^{-1}$ so  $0.1^{-3} = (10^{-1})^3 = 10^{-3}$.

And $\frac 1{10^{3}} = 10^{-3}$.

So $\frac {0.1^3}{10^3} = \frac {10^{-3}}{10^{3}} = 10^{-3 - 3}=10^{-6}$

....

or to view that whole thing fresh:

$q=\dfrac{0.9\times0.1^2}{9\times10^9\times1\times10^{-6}}=\require{cancel}$

$\frac {\cancel 9\times 10^{-1} \times 10^{-2}}{\cancel 9\times 10^9\times 10^0\times 10^{-6}}=$

$1 \times 10^{((-1) + (-2)) - (9 + 0 + (-6))}=1\times 10^{(-3) -(3)}= 1\times 10^{-6}$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
q = \frac{0.1^3}{10^3}=\frac{0.1*0.1*0.1}{10*10*10}=\frac{0.001}{1000}=0.000001 = 1*10^{-6}
\end{align}